# I am seeing 'xx' in CSS properties

Tags: css

I am seeing 'xx' in front of CSS properties (xxposition, xxoverflow, xx-min-height) throughout code samples online, but what is it? A lazy way of commenting out a property? Inquiring minds wanna know...

Example:

```
.content { 
border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc; 
xxposition:absolute; 
xxoverflow:hidden; 
xxmin-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: We dont know where did you get that code, what did you do to that code. So I don't think it's possible to answer you.

Comment: Only time I can remember seeing xx in CSS is in the font size. E.g. xx-small and xx-large.

Comment: @MíraKapičiak - I first found it in a stylesheet I inherited that is currently in production. But as I began researching other technical issues, I found it popping up in online samples. See the link below:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2038/optimizing-css-presentation-in-html-emails/

And yes, someone did answer me. But more specifically, you were not able to answer me. Thanks for the cheekiness, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly. That is a short term solution to commenting out rules or properties.

By changing an identifier it will miss the class or id that it originall targeted. By changing a style or value to a non-existant keyword, it becomes an invalid style and the browser will ignore it.

I use this technique myself, but only for deactivating styles when I am experimenting, I try not to leave any behind in the code.

Comment: yes I think it's unused code not properly commented or documented that accidentally made it into final copy.

I appreciate it!

Comment: Would be nice if someday if the CSS comment syntax was expanded to something like most other languages so that you didn't have to wrap rules with `/*` and `*/` and could just preface a line with `#` or `//`.

Comment: Agreed, commenting is a bit tricky in CSS.